# Permerror when testing multiple SPF records for Google Apps and MailChimp

Tags: domain-name-system, spam, google, spf, application

Our domain uses Google Apps for mail and Mailchimp for templated email campaigns. Mailchimp recommends adding an SPF record for their servers to decrease the likelihood of spam filter traps.

I have setup the SPF records below for WoodAcresSchool.org
 "v=spf1 include:servers.mcsv.net ~all"
 "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"

This appears to be the correct setup from what I have read from both vendors. However, when I test the records using check-auth@verifier.port25.com, I get "permerror (multiple SPF records). Details are below.

Does anyone have a suggestion how to correct this? I've tried a number of different configurations all with the same result. Most everything I've found focuses on a single SPF record - not multiple.

SPF check:          permerror
Sender-ID check:    permerror

### SPF check details:

Result:         permerror (multiple SPF records)
ID(s) verified: smtp.mail=jadkisson@woodacresschool.org
DNS record(s):
   woodacresschool.org. 3600 IN TXT "v=spf1 include:servers.mcsv.net ~all"
   woodacresschool.org. 3600 IN TXT "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"

Thanks in advance - Jeff Adkisson

Comment: Use the "Check MX" tool in the "G Suite Toolbox" to spot common MX record misconfigurations (and fixes): https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to include every thing in a single TXT record

Comment: Thank you... that put me on the right track. Here's what worked:

TXT "v=spf1 mx include:servers.mcsv.net include:_spf.google.com include: ~all"

----------------------------------------------------------
SPF check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         pass
ID(s) verified: smtp.mail=jadkisson@woodacresschool.org
DNS record(s):
   woodacresschool.org. 3600 IN TXT "v=spf1 mx include:servers.mcsv.net include:_spf.google.com include: ~all"

Comment: Why do you have a blank include at the end of the record ?

Answer (score 1):

You MUST NOT create multiple SPF records on a single domain. This will cause SPF to return PermError.

That is, if you have multiple SPF records on your domain, even all of them are valid, all your emails from that domain will fail SPF authentication.

You need to combine multiple services in ONE SPF record:

`v=spf1 include:servers.mcsv.net include:_spf.google.com ~all`

Learn more here: https://dmarcly.com/blog/can-i-have-multiple-spf-records-on-my-domain